# How to set default kernel to boot from?

Tags: linux, boot, linux-kernel

I have two linux images so far `4.19.0-2-amd64` and `4.19.0-kali3-amd64`. It starts with Debian as default but I want some packages from Kali. To group Kali packages, Debian separate in the Application Launcher(KDE) I need that `kali-menu` application.

After installing `kali-menu`, `katoolin` I saw there are some sort of other packages from Kali linux, `sources.list` changed, mirrors added & other changes:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep linux-image | awk '{print $2}'
linux-image-4.19.0-2-amd64
linux-image-4.19.0-kali3-amd64
```

older kernels & linux-image-headers cleaned-up using:

```
apt remove --purge linux-image-<image_name>
```

and/or

```
purge-old-kernels
```

Actually, it cause no harm or not slowing down the boot process. But, is it possible to set a default kernel without removing the extra one?

Comment: If you have Grub, see this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198003/set-default-kernel-in-grub

Comment: @Sam okay ... !