# Kali Linux Virtual Box 5.8.0 stuck on loading screen

Tags: linux, boot, kali-linux, grub

As the title suggests, everytime I try to boot into Kali Linux with 5.8.0 Kernel I get stuck at the loading screen (the dragon)
[image: kali stuck]
However, using the 5.7.0 Kernel seems to be no problem. At first I thought it was because of xfce and reinstalled it with gnome (which wasn't the problem) I tried editing the grub parameters for linux. Setting `nomodeset` instead of `quiet splash` resulted in another screen, where I wasn't stuck, but I could not do anything. And leaving `quiet nomodeset` results in a kernel panic.

I also once tried exporting Kali Linux from my Laptop and then imported in on my PC --> same errors.

Googling all kinds of combinations didn't get me anywhere. I don't know what to do anymore, but I need Kali for school.

My Host has an AMD Ryzen 5 2600 (--> maybe this is the cause)
The VM: 4 Cores, 4000MB RAM

Comment: If you can get a recovery prompt, then I suggest `update-initramfs -u`.  As far as I understand, it reconfigures your kernel to work with your hardware.  This has saved me lots of times when moving a virtual machine to bare-metal, or moving a hard-drive to a different motherboard.

Comment: If there is no specific reason to choose Kali, I would suggest to use a more common distribution, e.g. Ubuntu. If your teacher requires you to use Kali, he/she should also provide support if you have problems.

Comment: @Stewart did not help, but still thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sort-of fixed this issue, but going into advanced option, and selecting kernel 5.7.0. Then use this thread: [Set Default Kernel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198003/set-default-kernel-in-grub) to set as the default kernel. I have come to the assumption that 5.8.0 is buggy. Use 5.7.0 instead - that's what I'm now using.