# How to change the default kernel in GRUB

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, grub

I tried to change my grub file to select kernel 5.14.21, which is the 2nd one in the list:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=1
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

After doing `sudo update-grub`, I rebooted the computer and the problem persists. How can manually set my default kernel?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/421650/260833

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Holding shift does not take me to grub menu..

Answer (score 0):

Use this for the variables:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=my-special-boot-entry
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Additionally, in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` set an ID for your preferred entry:

```
menuentry 'My Linux' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --id 'my-special-boot-entry' {…
```

Removing `splash` and `quiet` in /etc/default/grub from  gives you the chance for debugging the behaviour.

I guess you've already found the helpful manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Simple-configuration.html